# awakeFromNimb doesn't get called on TableView reloadData Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an iPad TabBar navigation app and in `OrderViewController` I have a tableview on left side and outlets on the right side of the `view` as in a sort of split view controller. When you click a `tableView`'s `cell` it shows details on the other half screen. As I'm introducing two different color schemes for A/B testing, I use a switch to perform the change in color. The color switching dough doesn't succeed with `tableView`'s `cells`. Adding a `reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear`didn't solve the problem. 
Everything gets updated except for the cells, they maintain the colors of when they got created the first time. 
I added prints throughout the phases and I detected that cell's `awakeFromNimb`gets called only the first time. How do I get it to be called on `tableView.reloadData()`? As always many thanks.

awakeFromNib():

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureUi()
    }
```

viewWillAppear():

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.configureFetchedResultsController()
        orderTableView.delegate = self
        orderTableView.dataSource = self
        configureUI()
        orderTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Well short answer you don't. Awake from nib will and should only be called once. If you wanna update your UI just call configureUi() whenever you wanna call reload data.

Comment: @andromedainiative `configureUi()`is in cells custom class, how do I call it when I reload data?

Comment: You can use the tableView delegate. There is a function there called willDisplayCell. In that you can call the cells custom method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

Comment: For a `UITableViewCell` the `awakeFromNib` method is called when the cell is first created and the method `prepareForReuse` is called when the cell is about to be reused which includes when you use 'reloadData'.  So you can put the call of the cells `configureUI` in both of those.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tableView delegate willDisplayCell

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

```
class MyCustomVC: UITableViewDelegate {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
        willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
           forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

           guard var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? YourCustomCell else {
               return UITableViewCell()
           }

           cell.configureUi()
    }

}
```

Comment: I had to do minor changes, but still ain't working 100%: I had do omit `override`, also omit `indexPaht`as it was throwing an error o trying dequeing multiple time the same cell, and returning ÙITableViewCell()` unexpected non-void return

Comment: it now only creates new cells wit the right color scheme when scrolling, and when scrolling back some cell don't update.. any ideas?

Comment: @andromedainitiative calling `configureUi()`in `cellForRow` seems to work perfectly, but I'd like to use `willDisplayCell` as is the proper way to do it, any suggestion on my previous comments?

Comment: I think its fine to use it on either cellForRow or will display cell. Think of willDisplayCell as a place to fix the cell before its being reused. While cellForRow is more of one time constructor for that indexpath.